# Can characters have firearms such as flintlock pistols and rifles?

Tags: dnd-5e, firearms

I'm playing a game of D&D 5e with some friends. Are firearms such as flintlock pistols and rifles allowed?

Comment: What do you mean by “allowed”? The only person who can tell what is _allowed_ at a particular game is the DM, or in organised play the organisation in charge of the game. Are you perhaps trying to ask if there are rules for playing with guns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Possibly, it's up to the DM!

It is the DM, generally, who chooses the campaign setting, i.e. what "world" the players' adventures are going to take place in.

There are various published settings or a DM is free to create his own.

Most of the established settings use a more fantasy-medieval level of technology (with magic of course). Some settings - such as Eberron - are rather more advanced either technologically or in a 'magi-tech' kind of way.

A DM making his own campaign setting can choose any level of technology he likes, although the basic rules are geared more towards medieval fantasy. The Dungeon Master's Guide does contain optional rules on guns however, if you decide they exist in your campaign!

Comment: You can also provide the DMG bits about this to show there are rules for it.

Comment: ^ "are there rules for it" might be essentially what the querent is trying to ask, too.

Answer (score 31):

### The DMG has optional rules for Firearms and Alien technology.

[Firearms](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Firearms) and [Alien Technology](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#AlienTechnology) are covered in DMG Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop (p. 267-268). All of the rules in that chapter are optional, and you are well advised to consider this part from the [introduction of the chapter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop) (p. 263):

> This chapter contains optional rules that you can use to customize
> your campaign, [...] Some of them are variants of rules, and others are
> entirely new rules. Each option represents a different genre, style of
> play, or both. [...] Before you add a new rule to your campaign, ask
> yourself two questions:
>
> - Will the rule improve the game?
> - Will my players like it?
>
> If you're confident that the answer to both questions
> is yes, then you have nothing to lose by giving it a try.

The Firearms table (p. 268) describes cost, damage, weight and properties of pistols, rifles and other firearms.

Comment: Thank you for providing the optional rules!